# Data not showing on Tableau worksheet at all

Tags: data-science, tableau-api, data-analysis

I am very new to Tableau, and am following a very simple tutorial, but am having trouble with even the first step.

I have imported an excel spreadsheet to Tableau, where it has auto-sorted the dimensions and measures.
It allows me to put one of the 'region' dimensions to the sheet, but not a SUM(Units)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCb34.jpg <- example video

Comment: Which version of `Tableau` are you using?  Video shows that it is not latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You could have resized your viz accidentally.

To undo this. At the Menu Bar, Go to **Worksheet**  -> **Clear** -> **Manual Sizing**